# Insert Json file to sql table (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have an old scheme, and I want to add a new field.
The new field type is JSON,
I added it with -

```
alter table <Table> add json_field JSON
```

when I am trying to do

```
Update <Table> SET json_field ='{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "car": null
}' where id='123'
```

I got -

> Token "name" is invalid. CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {
> name...

How can I add a JSON file to the table? I have to add a big JSON, so it is necessary to add it with minimal changes.
Thanks!

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=98f9cb0a4f27c0ace17b40afe3fbf041). Note that it's recommended to use `jsonb` rather than `json`

Comment: Looks like the double quotes around "name" are missing in your real SQL statement. You do however show them in your example.